# MinGW/Cygwin deploy to other computers?

Tags: deployment, cygwin, mingw

Quick question: If I write a program in c++ and compile using cygwin/mingw, how can I get the binary to work on computers that does not have cygwin? In other words how can I deploy to PC without cygwin?

I tried to simply compile with cygwin but when run on other computers, a bunch dll are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ship the DLLs, obviously. However, depending on what you are doing you may not need Cygwin at all . So the question is, what are the DLLs that are missing, and what are you doing.

Comment: thx for the quick reply! my experience was i wrote a hello world in c++, tried it on a different computer it tells me cygwin.dll and a bunch other dll are missing :(

Comment: @poly OK, you don't need cygwin if you are not trying to run POSIX code, certainly not to write hello world. Download the GCC distribution from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net and use that. cygwin is, frankly, a big pile of pooh.